# Deleting a new version of an existing ios app ,when its binary has not been uploaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have tried to upload a new version for an existing app in itunes connect.I have not uploaded the binary.And its status is prepare for upload.Now i want to delete this version from my itunes connect account.How can i achieve it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you can change the version number and very thing, but you can't delete it.

Just don't upload any binary and change the version number and update text when you are ready to upload an new version.